# Overloading operator++ to find and return successor node of binary search tree

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, binary-search-tree

This is the relevant portion of my code involving overloading the operator++ to find and return a successor node of a binary search tree. I've tested the tree itself, and it forms correctly, and cout's correctly using an inorder traversal function.

But I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong with overloading the operator++. I've tried many different versions, and this latest one, nextInorderSuccessor, returns the successor perfectly when /not/ called from within the overloaded operator++

This, along with the fact that I've made multiple version of the operator++, lead me to believe that I'm just handling the actual overloaded operator wrong. Can anyone offer any insight?

WCBst is my tree class. curr, which is being incremented, is a node. That's why I returned a node.

```
void WCBst::write_to_file()
{
//  ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("WCBst.txt");
    curr = minValue(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < count;i++)
    {

        cout << '{' << curr->data.first << ',' << curr->data.second << "}\n";
        outFile << '{' << curr->data.first << ',' << curr->data.second << "}\n";
        ++curr;

    }
node *WCBst::operator++() 
{
    return nextInorderSuccessor(root, curr);
}
node* WCBst::nextInorderSuccessor(node* root, node* tofind) {


    node* successor = NULL;
    if (tofind->right) {
        successor = tofind->right;
        while (successor->left) {
            successor = successor->left;
        }
    }
    else {
        while (root) {
            if (tofind->data < root->data) {
                successor = root;
                root = root->left;
            }
            else if (tofind->data > root->data) {
                root = root->right;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return successor;
}
```

Comment: What is `WCBst`? Is that your tree? Why does incrementing a tree return a `node *`? Please add some clarifications.

Comment: Should I not be returning, or incrementing on the node? is that where I'm going wrong? And if so, what should I do instead?

Comment: `operator++` should return the same type, if you have `WCBst::operator++` it should return `WCBst&`. But I think it is not a good idea to abuse operators to do things that are completely different from the original meaning.

Comment: I've also tried it with node*::operator++ and obtained the exact same result.

Comment: You should be incrementing the node, but you are incrementing the tree. What people usually do is make a `NodeIterator WCBst::begin();` that gets you the first node when you dereference the `NodeIterator`. Then you can make a `NodeIterator &NodeIterator::operator++();` that walks the tree. You can maybe use `node` as the `NodeIterator`.